# Why tf.layers.Flatten doesn't change shape?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to understand how tf.layers.Flatten works.
After running the session, shape still remains (5,4). Why not change?

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

X = tf.constant(np.array([[1, 5, 9, 13], [2, 6, 10, 14], [3, 7, 11, 15], [4, 8, 12, 16], [17, 18, 19, 20]]))
flatten_layer = tf.layers.Flatten()
Y = flatten_layer(X)

sess = tf.Session()
result = sess.run(Y)

print(result.shape)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this is a layer class. It expects one of the dimensions, first by default, to be batch size. So it won't work with shape (5,4).

```
X = tf.constant(np.random.rand(1,5,4))
flatten_layer = tf.layers.Flatten()
Y = tf.layers.flatten(X)

sess = tf.Session()
result = sess.run(Y)
print(X.shape)  #(1,5,4)
print(result.shape) #(1,20)
```

For tensors you can use `tf.reshape`